# unable to insert 'FALSE' from php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the function query to insert data to a mysql table from php.  The function, call and database structure are show below.

I have two questions:
1) why does the error message say invalid datetime format.  The column customCrew is a tinyint.
2) I am able to insert 0 or 1 but how come I can't insert 'FALSE' or FALSE for this column?

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */){    
   // SQL statement    
   $sql = func_get_arg(0);

   // parameters, if any    
   $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);   

   // try to connect to database    
   static $handle;    
   if (!isset($handle)){    
      try{    
         // connect to database    
         $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

         // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL    
         $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);    
      }catch (Exception $e){    
         echo 'help';   

         // trigger (big, orange) error    
         trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);    
         exit;    
      }    
   }   

   // prepare SQL statement    
   $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);    
   if ($statement === false){

      // trigger (big, orange) error    
      trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);      
      exit;    
   }    

   // execute SQL statement    
   $results = $statement->execute($parameters);   

   // return result set's rows, if any    
   if ($results !== false){    
      return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
   }else{    
      return false;    
   }    
}
```

here is php statement to use above function:

```
query("INSERT INTO sails ( type,
                           date,
                           skipperId,
                           boat,
                           class,
                           resStart,
                           resEnd,
                           resTS,
                           spots,
                           customCrew)
                           VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                           'RES',
                           $_POST['date'],
                           $_POST['skipperId'],
                           $_POST['boat'],
                           "50",
                           date('H:i', strtotime($_POST['start'])),
                           date('H:i', strtotime($_POST['end'])),
                           $response['now'],
                           $_POST['spots'],
                           'FALSE');
```

structure of table sails:

```
1   type                varchar(4)  utf8mb4_general_ci      No  None            
2   date Primary        date                                No  None            
3   skipperId Primary   int(11)                             No  None            
4   boat                varchar(20) utf8mb4_general_ci      No  None            
5   class               varchar(4)  utf8mb4_general_ci      No  None            
6   resStart            time                                No  None            
7   resEnd              time                                No  None            
8   resTS               datetime                            No  None            
9   sailStart           time                                Yes NULL            
10  sailEnd             time                                Yes NULL            
11  sailTS              datetime                            Yes NULL            
12  spots               int(11)                             No  None            
13  customCrew          tinyint(1)                          No  None            
14  xclTS               datetime                            Yes NULL
```

and here's the error message from the console:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 
Incorrect integer value: 'FALSE' for column `sandbox`.`sails`.`customCrew` at row 1 in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/lagin/includes/functions.php:177
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/lagin/includes/functions.php(177): PDOStatement-&gt;execute(Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/lagin/public/skipper.php(64): query('INSERT INTO sai...', 'RES', '2021-07-29', 
'1', 'Irlbach', '50', '09:00', '20:30', '2021-07-28 17:4...', '3', 'FALSE')
```

Comment: `customCrew` is of type `tinyint` and you try to enter a string. That's clearly wrong. Try to enter a number like 0 or 1. You can also use MySQL constants `TRUE` or `FALSE` which are 0 or 1 respectively, but that can't be done via binding

Comment: did you read the question? 'FALSE' and  FALSE both don't work.  mysql is suppose to convert to 0 or 1

Comment: Change `'FALSE'` to `0` and it will work

Comment: use BOOLEAN bit the result is also 0 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7ce1677e00684e0466c8906e8b5603d5

Comment: Also, please enable PDO exception mode instead of this messy error checking. It will save you a lot of trouble.